# What do i ve to do if i want to use same apex(oracle) from other PC in the same network?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-apex

I had installed oracle 11g in my system. I want to access oracle, especially oracle-apex from other PC in the same network. I am able to work on oracle apex via my pc. Since, it is being hosted locally,I was able to access within the PC. I tried with ip adderess from other PC in the same network. But I couldn't.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any external Apex listener or is this integrated XML DB HTTP server? in the latter case a change in the configuration might help
try running

```
DBMS_XDB.SETLISTENERLOCALACCESS (FALSE)
```

Also, pay close attention on the server configuration, for example http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb_web_services.htm and many other resources